# how to "manually" process file upload with symfony2?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, file-upload

Because I have a custom built jQuery plugin to pass file uploads to my symfony2 webapp I am looking for ways to handle this upload in the controller.

The standard (non-ajax) file upload that I currently have (and that works fine for synchronous calls) looks like this

**Controller excerpt**

```
    ...

    $entity  = new Image();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new ImageType($createAction), $entity);
    $form->bind($request); // <-- Find a way to make this connection manually?!

    //check that a file was chosen
    $fileExists = isset($entity->file);

    if ( ($form->isValid()) && ($fileExists) ) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

    }

    ...
```

**Form Type**: The form just takes the file and a name:

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{

    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $createAction = $this->createAction;

        if ($createAction) {        
            $builder
                ->add('file')
            ;
        }

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Namn'))
        ;
    }

    ...

}
```

As I understand (or in other words DON'T apparently understand) the file upload system with symfony2 and doctrine there is quite a bit of magic going on underneath the hood on this call

```
$form->bind($request);
```

For example, if I skip this bind() and instead try to create the Image entity manually like this...

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $parent = $request->request->get('parent');
    $file = $request->request->get('file1');
    $name = $request->request->get('name');

    $entity->setName( $name );
    $entity->setFile( $file );
    $entity->setFolder( null );
```

... I find that it doesn't even have a setFile() so that is taken care of in some other way. Here is that **Image entity**:

```
namespace BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Bilden måste ha ett namn")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $width
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="width", type="integer")
     */
    private $width;

    /**
     * @var integer $height
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="height", type="integer")
     */
    private $height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;


//The deleteRequested variable is to flag that an image has been deleted by user.
//Due to slideshow issues we can however not delete the image right away, we can't risk to remove it from the
//cache manifest before the slideshow round is up.

    /**
     * @var time $deleteRequested
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="delete_requested", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deleteRequested;


    /**
    * @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $company;     

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="folder", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $folder;


    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="12000000")
     */
     public $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage", mappedBy="image")
     */
    protected $qr;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }    

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();

    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/images/'.$this->getCompany()->getId();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set width
     *
     * @param integer $width
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    /**
     * Get width
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * Set height
     *
     * @param integer $height
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    /**
     * Get height
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company $company
     */
    public function setCompany(\BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company 
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set folder
     *
     * @param BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder $folder
     */
    public function setFolder(\BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder $folder = NULL)
    {
        $this->folder = $folder;
    }

    /**
     * Get folder
     *
     * @return BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder 
     */
    public function getFolder()
    {
        return $this->folder;
    }


    /**
     * Set qr
     *
     * @param BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage $qr
     */
    public function setQr(\BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage $qr = null)
    {
        $this->qr = $qr;
    }

    /**
     * Get qr
     *
     * @return BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\QrImage 
     */
    public function getQr()
    {
        return $this->qr;
    }


    /**
     * Set deleteRequested
     *
     * @param date $deleteRequested
     */
    public function setDeleteRequested($deleteRequested = null)
    {
        $this->deleteRequested = $deleteRequested;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleteRequested
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getDeleteRequested()
    {
        return $this->deleteRequested;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of advice: avoid mixing forms and entities like the plague.  Write the extra code to handle it yourself.  Trust me, this ^this^ won't be the last time they give you trouble.

Comment: The way I did it is right out of the Symfony2 cookbook... http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: Flosculus how can I handle file upload in controller?

Comment: have you tried to directly access $_FILES php superglobal from your controller ? this should work.

Comment: It feels like hacking sym2, not exactly what I'm looking to do... I think =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. To access the files uploaded to symfony from the controller, you just need to do this:

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $file = $request->files->get('file1'); //file1 being the name of my form field for the file

    /* if your entity is set up like mine - like they teach you in the symfony2 cookbook
     * file is actually a public property so you can just set it like this
     **/
    $entity->file = $file; 

    //and here's how you get the original name of that file
    $entity->setName( $file->getClientOriginalName() );
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you want to get an entity with your file after form submit/bind/handleRequest or smth else, you need to provide `data_class` option in form configuration method (`setDefaultOptions` etc.). And only after that your form will start to return needed entity after submission.

Comment: There is no problem with this setup in synchronous requests that actually use the form type, my only issue was getting to the uploaded file in the controller for when I was using an ajax submit with custom data.

Answer (score 3):

1)First of All create your entity :

```
namespace XXX;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

      /**
     * @var string $image
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

}
```

2) build your form: So we will then create a simple form type for this Article entity in order to fit into the other forms: ArticleType.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('image')
            ->add('...')

        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'xxx_articletype';
    }
}
```

3)Create the controller: The controller below shows you how to manage the whole process: ArticleController.php:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * Article controller.
 *
 */
class ArticleController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Article entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('XXXBundle:Article')->find($id);
        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
        }
    return $this->render('XXXBundle:Article:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,

        ));
    }
    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Article entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Article();
        //$entity = $em->getRepository('CliniqueGynecoBundle:Article');
        $form   = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $entity);

        return $this->render('XXXBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Article entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $entity  = new Article();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $entity);
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('article_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

        }

        return $this->render('XXXBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

4) layout for the upload form: new.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('basearticle_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

5) Display layout: show.html.twig

```
<table>
 <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><img src="{{ asset('upload/' ~ entity.id ~'/' ~ entity.image)}}" alt="" height="525" width="666" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

6) Use the « Lifecycle Callbacks » hooking the entity in a « Lifecycle callbacks »: « @ ORM \ HasLifecycleCallbacks »

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
....
```

7) Added methods to download files:

```
class Article
{
   ....................................

    public function getFullImagePath() {
        return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->image;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/";
    }

    protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/upload/';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function uploadImage() {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!$this->id){
            $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }else{
            $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        $this->setImage($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function moveImage()
    {
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
            mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
        }
        copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image, $this->getFullImagePath());
        unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function removeImage()
    {
        unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
```